# server/Client C#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, streamreader, streamwriter

I'm getting tired of working in vb.net, vb6, and C#. So i have decided to convert everything I'm using into one programming language which is C#. My problem right now is what I should use for a 2-d game. I'm trying to build a client/server for a small 2-d game. What I need is to figure out which would be best for about a server that will most likely hold about 5 - 30 (maybe more) people at a time. I heard UPD is better than TCP but I'm not sure. I want to use BinaryWriter and BinaryReader with the server. Another part I'm having trouble to figure out is how to set it up so that the server will read data from the client but then call a function or a sbu and pass the data to that which will then handle it and create a file or do something else then if it needs to send data back to the server. Any help would be great. Eventually I would like to use this client/server as a base for a small 3-D board game I'm working on in Unity3D.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your actual question is. "How do I write a client/server game in C#" is way too broad to ask here. You'll need to get a book that explains client-server development for the .NET Framework.

Comment: Let me ask a different way then. I'm trying to convert an exsisting program that uses Winsock. Its an open source 2-d game "engine" created in vb6 called Eclipse Origins. I would like to keep the same set up. The article Jess left explains a lot. Only problem is it was in C++. So I'll have to figure out how to do the same but in C# now.

Answer (score 0):

For networked gaming where the 'action' is happening quickly, UDP is much better.  Rather than write a long paragraph, here is a link with similar thoughts to mine.

http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/udp-vs-tcp/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although its in C++ it should help me get started. I also found some information on UPD and binary writer after some more searching.

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0580__Network/UseTcpClienttowritetoreadfromaserver.htm

I should be able to adapt this into UPD with some testing. Again thanks for the article.